# Not able to run vnstat unless as root in debian

Tags: linux, debian, root

So, I need to run this command:

```
vnstat -tr
```

But as a user I just created, not as root, as root it works fine, but as a regular user I get this:

```
Error: Unable to get interface "eth0" statistics.
Error: Interface "eth0" not available, exiting.
```

Operating system: Debian Linux 6.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was grsecurity locking /proc/net/dev from viewing it by users. The solution was to downgrade from ovhs linux core from 3.10.X to 3.8.13.